# How to write Linq query for a Json file?

Tags: json, linq

I need to write a Linq query in a specific format for a json file. There are 3 tables in the Database. 
Student, with Student Id and name.
Subject, with Subject Id and name.
Results with Student Id, Student Id, Result and Date of Result.
This is my Query to get Results

```
   var studentQuery = (from c in db.Students
                       join f in db.Results
                       on c.ID equals f.StudentID
                       join d in db.Subjects
                       on f.SubjectID equals d.ID
                       where c.ID == Convert.ToInt32(DropDownList1.SelectedValue)
                       select new newResult{
                                    ID = f.StudentID,
                                    Date = convertDateToUTC(f.Date.Value),
                                    Name = c.Name.Trim(),
                                    Result1 = f.Result1.Value,
                                    Type = d.Subject1.Trim()
                                })
                      .ToList();

   return studentQuery;
```

But I wish to return the query in the 
in the format below

```
[ { "name": "Denis P6 Results", "type": "English", "data": [ [ 1325431800000, 54 ], [ 1325691000000, 65 ], [ 1325950200000, 73 ], [ 1326209400000, 60 ] ] },

{ "name": "Denis P6 Results", "type": "Maths", "data": [ [ 1325518200000, 76 ], [ 1325777400000, 81 ], [ 1326036600000, 80 ], [ 1326295800000, 70 ] ] },

{ "name": "Denis P6 Results", "type": "Science", "data": [ [ 1325604600000, 80 ], [ 1325863800000, 75 ], [ 1326123000000, 69 ], [ 1326382200000, 68 ] ] },

{ "name": "Mak P6 Results", "type": "English", "data": [ [ 1325431800000, 57 ], [ 1325691000000, 49 ], [ 1325950200000, 66 ], [ 1326209400000, 70 ] ] },

{ "name": "Mak P6 Results", "type": "Maths", "data": [ [ 1325518200000, 80 ], [ 1325777400000, 83 ], [ 1326036600000, 85 ], [ 1326295800000, 79 ] ] },

{ "name": "Mak P6 Results", "type": "Science", "data": [ [ 1325604600000, 67 ], [ 1325863800000, 69 ], [ 1326123000000, 66 ], [ 1326382200000, 62 ] ] } ]
```

I really need some help as I've been searching for days. I am a total newbie at this.
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Let's break this down into each of the steps you're trying to achieve:

1. Group the results, by person and subject.
2. Render these into JSON.

For the first bit, we can do something like

```
var groupedResults = from result in db.Results
                     group result by new { result.StudentID, result.SubjectID } into grouping
                     select new { grouping.Key, grouping };

var resultsWithName = from result in groupedResults
                      join student in db.Students on result.Key.StudentID equals student.ID
                      join subject in db.Subjects on result.Key.SubjectID equals subject.ID
                      select new
                      {
                          result.Key,
                          student.Name,
                          subject.Type,
                          result.grouping
                      };
```

`resultsWithName` now contains a sequence of name and subject pairs, together with a sequence of the results. This is the first bit done.

You could use a library for generating the JSON, but this isn't too bad to do by hand:

```
var jsonRendered = resultsWithName.Select(g =>
    string.Format("{{ \"name\" : \"{0} Results\", \"type\" : \"{1}\", \"data\" : {2} }}",
        g.Name,
        g.Type,
        "[ " + string.Join(", ", g.grouping.Select(r => string.Format("[ {0}, {1} ]", r.Date, r.Mark))) + " ]"));
```

Here, we iterate over all the grouped results (i.e. for each person and each subject), then create a single string containing the results for that subject.

I haven't used quite the same names for some of the variables as you, but hopefully it's clear how to adapt this for your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var json = serializer.Serialize(resultsWithName);
```

Just use the built in .NET json serializer. No need to make it too complicated.